# PHP 4- ignore parse errors?

Tags: php, php4, parse-error

I have a script that uses a PHP 5 syntax that's apparently not supported in PHP 4.

like MyClass::method()->method(...)

I'm trying to display a error at the beginning of the script telling that the server doesn't have PHP 5 installed, and "die" nicely, but I can't because I get that stupid parse error...

So how can I make PHP ignore errors if < 5 ?

Comment: Why do you still have to deal with PHP 4 in the first place?

Comment: Cannot work around parser failures. You can check the `PHP_VERSION` constant though and write a nicer error message. But not in the same script, you have to test it **before** the potentially failing code gets invoked.

Comment: why does PHP have to "parse" the code first, why doesn't just execute it?

Comment: Parsing is part of the execution process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to have one file that includes another if PHP5 *is* installed:

```
//index.php
if (intval(substr(phpversion(), 0, 1)) < 5) {
    die ('you must have PHP 5 installed');
} else {
    include('main.php');
}

//main.php
MyClass::method()->method(); // or whatever
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.0.0', '<')) {
        die('PHP is to old.');
    }
```

http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#reserved.constants.core

or

http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php

Comment: This, of course, is the correct solution. Correct but for the typo, that is ;)

Comment: Will not work because the parse error triggers before any code is executed.

Comment: sure, that must part of the bootstrap process

Answer (score 0):

It can't ignore the errors, however it can die nicely if error_reporting(0);

Comment: Will not work because the parse error triggers before any code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((int)phpversion() < 5){
  error_reporting(0);
}
```

Comment: Will not work because the parse error triggers before any code is executed.